# Best way to list users with customClaims

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I just trying to list users in **Firebase function**

And I want to list just users if an **admin** (customClaims)

Now I do like this and its work

```
exports.listAdmins = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {});
  const token = req.body.token;
  try {
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
    if (decodedToken) {
      let users = [];
      const list = async (nextPageToken) => {
        await admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken).then(async (result) => {
          result.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
            const user = userRecord.toJSON();
            if (user.customClaims && user.customClaims.admin) {
              users.push(user);
            }
          });
          if (result.pageToken) {
            await list(result.pageToken)
          }
        })
      };
      await list()
      res.status(200).send({
        success: 'SUCCESS',
        users: users
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({error: 'SOMETHING_WRONG'});
  }
});
```

But I was wondering **about performance** if I had many 100000 users?

Any better way to filter the list? by using `admin.auth().listUsers()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation for [Auth.listUsers()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#listUsers), there is just listUsers(), and there is no alternative to filter users by any criteria.  Listing many users could obviously be kind of an expensive operation.  Consider instead storing information about your users in a database, and query the database instead.

You are also free to [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) for functionality that you think is missing from any Firebase SDK.

Comment: Thanks!, filed a request. But I am not sure this is usable for the another. :)